# "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Mustache" in Unit Tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mustache

im running a rails app which im running Unit tests on the Javascript side (Using Teaspoon/Jasmine).

the funny thing is, on the function I call I KNOW `Mustache.render` function is working (Im able to console.log it's return value (which is the `Mustache.render` function) and see that it is working. However when I call that function from my unit tests im getting a:

`Failure/Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Mustache`.

For reference I don't actually call the Mustache render function directly im simply calling the function that uses it and grabbing it's return value to check again.

I've been able to successfully grab and use various other functions and use them just fine, this one is just giving me trouble. Can the Mustache.render object not exist outside it's own file or scope or something?

Edit: Example code:

```
_makeSomething: function viewMakeSomething(data) {
      const template = templates.something;

      return Mustache.render(document.querySelector(template).innerHTML, data);
    }
```

and my test code is simply:

```
  it('_makeSomething object', function() {

    let obj = {id: 1234, content: "_makeSomething Assertion", author: "Test User"}
    let $something = _makeSomething(obj);
  });
```

(Right now im just capturing it before I assert anything or split it up/etc...., but it's just calling it at all)

Comment: Can you show the Code, please?

Comment: Sure, i'll add an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you teaspoon doesn't have access to your dev/production assets pipelene. You should specify what JS to load for your tests. This is necessary to prevent loading all files from manifest to test some feature. Because this is unit testing.

From [example](https://github.com/jejacks0n/teaspoon#writing-specs):

```
//= require mustache
describe("My great feature", function() {

  it("will change the world", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
    expect(Mustache).toBeDefined();
  });

});
```

Comment: I noticed the file itself (Which uses `Mustache` doesn't require it, nor does any of it's `import files` require it at all either). I know it was just installed as a npm package...but I don't see it being included anywhere.

Comment: I did try adding `//=require Mustache` to my spec_helpers file (Which is what teaspoon suggested) with zero luck unfortunately

Comment: According to [docs](https://github.com/mustache/mustache) `Mustache`  is a ruby class and you cannot call it like you do in js file. You need to find some adapter to do this or proper gem.